# An efficient method for executing external programs in PHP?

Tags: php, c, encryption, network-programming

I am writing a web application for storing files in an encrypted form but which can later be decrypted in a non-php environment. So, lets say a user has uploaded a file named `doc.pdf`. 
Then it is encrypted and stored on server in encrypted form. The user then may download the encrypted file later on and decrypt it on his/her system.

Because files encrypted using php's mcrypt extension are non-portable, I decided to write a program in c called "encrypt". Then I invoke it in php:

```
$return_var=exec("encrypt $file_path $key");
```

Now, another method that I thought of was to create an encryption server which is basically a wrapper around the encrypt program with the capability of listening to requests through sockets. So lets say the php script will now make a request to this program providing a file name and the key to encrypt.

I thought that this could be a more flexible approach as the load of encryption process can be adjusted easily by putting the encryption server program on another computer.

Now, my question is which one of the two approaches is efficient (in terms of speed, handling large no. of clients etc.)?

Comment: It would really pay off if you could stream the incoming data to something that performs the encryption, and then directly write it to disk. Processing files as if it is a batch process will be much less efficient, if only because you will have to load the data into memory an X number of times, and possibly even from disk (which is potentially unsafe as well).

Answer (score 1):

Most of the encryption process will be spent in performing symmetric encryption, e.g. AES. AES - and most cryptographic ciphers - are relatively fast. There is a lot of chance that you will be waiting on I/O rather than the encryption part. Creating a server application for this is almost certainly overkill. I would go for a local application first and only revert to what is basically optimalization later, if it is really required.

Comment: I agree with u ,but lets say on my main server both web server and database server are running then performing encryption on the same server is likely to increase load. So would not it better to use a server application. Any way I/O can be optimized on server side by using lets say high speed connection. Am i wrong ? btw thanx for the input

Comment: i agree with @owlstead. possibly it would be the best solution to write this in PHP and then cluster your application. (ie: move to cloud)

Comment: @Kail Yeah, clustering the PHP application (again, if required) would be my solution as well. The only reason why I would make a specialized server is for architectural or security purposes (keeping the key safe and accessability to a minimum), not so much for performance reasons. But I would start by getting it working (creating some CLI tools as well), then beautify it and work up from there.

Answer (score 0):

it may perform well better if you would do the encryption in PHP without executing an external program which induces a very huge overhead.

Look into the mcrypt extension:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php

and just write the resulting string to the target file.

Comment: I initially thought about it and even implemented it. But when decrypting the file using a c program , it just never worked. I have searched for it a lot and found that encryption using php mcrypt's extension is non-portable.

Comment: it is portable - most possibly you used incompatible ciphers when encrypting and decrypting. When you get all the cipher parameters right, you can encrypt the data with every other language. in fact, mcrypt is just a wrapper for C functions.

Comment: Well , if u say so i will go through my implementation again. thanx

Comment: Little advise, leave no parameter to the default value. The algorithms are always the same, but each platform will have different defaults and this is where differences come from, aside from byte orders and encodings. If you know what each argument is, you will have an easier time.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply for reasons of documents just `ZIP` / compress the files with a password, and keep that password saved for the users download, etc.

That way the user does not need any decryption tools on their end and the encryption / zip protection is already done for you.

I realize not what you are asking, but I would go that way in order NOT to simply re-invent the wheel, and still achieve the same result, protected file.

Comment: Actually my requirement is a bit complex, i have to use multiple encryption algorithms which can vary from one file to another. Morever, system should not be limited only to documents.